# When submitting a form, the action method is returning null for parameter sizes if the form data is too large. ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 - and am coding using visual studio 2019.

I have a simple form that sends two text values to the server, however, these text values can be quite long (imagine A3 size Images @ 300dpi in base64 image format).

These upload fine whilst testing on localhost using IIS Express if the file size is quite small, but if the text strings get longer (ie bigger image files), then the parameters on the action are null. I understand that the upload limit is huge and the file strings I am uploading are around 15MB.

My code is as follows:

View:

```
<form id="df" asp-controller="Design" asp-action="SortAndSave"  method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="data2" id="data2" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="image2" id="image2" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="full" id="full" value="@full.ToString().ToLower()" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SortAndSave(string image2, string data2)
        {
}
```

Again, when I use small images it works fine, when I use large images, the values returned are null.  When I use large images and I use Request.Form.Keys, this returns null as well.

I have researched for two days now, and can't work out what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RequestSizeLimitAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.requestsizelimitattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to specify the request size limit. Specify it over the request action method like this:

```
[RequestSizeLimit("specify size in bytes")]
public ActionResult SortAndSave(string image2, string data2)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked in conjunction with  this
 [RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = 60000000)]

Comment: Glad it helped.